# If $g(f(x))$ is injective, is $g$ injective?

Tags: functions

I know if $g(f(x))$ is injective, then $f$ is injective and I have no problems proving this, but I also know g is not injective, but my following wrong proof suggests that $g$ is injective.

*Proof:* If $g(f(x))$ is injective, then if $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$, then $x_1=x_2$, so $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and $y_1=y_2$ for some $y_1$ and $y_2$. Since $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, so $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$ implies $y_1=y_2$, so $g$ is injective.
Can anyone point out where my proof is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To prove that$g$ is injective you  have to start with $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$ (and prove that $y_1=y_2$) not with $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$

Comment: You can get a good intuition about this with drawing a Venn Diagram. if the composition is injective, you can only tell about $g(f(A))$ where A is the domain of the first function f. You can not figure out anything about the "rest" of the domain of the function g.

Comment: But if I need to prove that if g(f(x)) is surjective, then g is surjective. One proof is:for every z in Z there exists x in X such that g(f(x))=z, and replace f(x) with y I can get g(y)=z, thus for every z, there exists y in Y. Why can I start with similar thing here?

Comment: Here's a counterexample: Take $f:\{*\}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ sending $*\mapsto 0$ and $g$ the unique map $\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{*\}$. Your proof works only if every $y$ is $=f(x)$, for some $x$, so you only proved that $g$ is 1-1 in $f(A)$

Comment: Take any injective function $f$ whose range is properly contained in the domain of $g.$ For instance let us take $f = \text {id}_{[0,1]}$ and $g : [-1,1] \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $g(x) = |x|,$ for all $x \in [-1,1].$

Comment: Yeah, but as I said why can this proof be correct: if I need to prove that if g(f(x)) is surjective, then g is surjective. One proof is:for every z in Z there exists x in X such that g(f(x))=z, and replace f(x) with y I can get g(y)=z, thus for every z, there exists y in Y. Why can I start with similar thing(starting with g(f(x))=z,but not similar way for the wrong proof ) here?